# Split Streets to Create Polygons

Tags: algorithm, gis, postgis, openstreetmap, computational-geometry

I have a need to take all the streets belonging to a certain area (in OSM) and split each street by each other and form polygons from the segments that result from the split operation. I would like to know whether such a function exists in the GIS tools that are available or if the algorithm needs to be written. If I should write the algorithm, what would be a good way to approach the problem?

If the street network looks like below, polygons like given in red needs to be created

[image: If the street network looks like this, polygons like given in red needs to be created]